# Parsing HTML - get only a subset of table rows

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have a problem - I need to get a few rows from an HTML table on a web page. I have a method that retrieves the content of a random website as a string, but now I need to parse it. I tried to do that using something like this:

Example HTML:

```
<table>
 <tr class="test">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>  
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="test2>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>  
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
   </tr>
 <tr class="test3>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>  
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
   </tr>
```

With this example HTML, I need only the values, eg: 5, 6, 7, 8. So I have this method, defined using JSoup:

```
String url = "a.html";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements div = doc.select("table.domains-market-table.tbody.tr");

Element masthead = doc.select("table.domains-market-table").last();
```

But this gets the contents of the entire div, whereas I want to get each of the elements. Can anyone help me resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `nth-of-type(n)` selector?

Something like this perhaps:

```
Elements div = doc.select("table.domains-market-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(2)");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector should be: `Elements div = doc.select("table.domains-market-table tr td");`, whereas `domains-market-table` must be a class defined in `<table>` tag.
Unless you give the HTML file, I can't help you with correct selector.